# How to change the color of a div tag in html with javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change the color of a div tag in HTML with JavaScript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="myDiv">
  //your code goes here
</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = "red";
</script>
```

You have to trigger this is somehow like on body load or on button click

Answer (score 0):

```js
// selecting the html element using id

var div = document.getElementById("apple");
div.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div id="apple">
  <p>some text</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: This will change only the color of the text inside it